# photoshop - how to make a layer on top of all layers effect all layers except one down

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, transparency

I using a transparent grunge texture on a street building layers I maked using shape tool so I want that transparent texture to effect on the whole building layers except the window glasses so how to do that i can't move the glass layers top on the grunge texture that's will destroy the whole design
are there any other way to do that ?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried [**Layer Masks**](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html)?

Comment: @Scott no i did't   ? i have the glass layers free not marged should i use selection tools for that or there are another way ?

Comment: Have you tried arranging your layers differently so that the grunge texture is below the window layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the layers to be affected by the textrure.

Select the texture Layer.

Create a Clipping mask.

Now your Texture will only affect the layers inside the group.

Image below.

[image]